# How to conditionally replace values in Pandas Dataframe column if the column contains lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working on a project where a Pandas dataframe is necessary. One of the columns have samples of engine rpm data. Sometimes the values can be off by a significant amount, which is just caused by issues from the sensors. I'm looking for a way to replace entries where the average of the samples are too large. I've tried something like this:

```
dataframe.loc[((not any(np.isnan(rpm)) and mean(rpm) > 10000) for rpm in dataframe[ENGINE_RPM])] = np.nan
```

But this crashes due to to pandas core indexing error. Anyone know a good to way to accomplish this?

Comment: why are you equating it to np.nan ?

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter, I could replace it with None. Right below I use isnull() to replace all nans with None so I can shove into a plotly graph.

Comment: `dataframe[dataframe.loc[((not any(np.isnan(rpm)) and mean(rpm) > 10000) for rpm in dataframe[ENGINE_RPM])] = np.nan]
`

Comment: I am not sure if that will work, but try it out and let me know, because it seems that you are storing None or Nan in the dataframe for those conditions !

Comment: That actually threw a syntax error unfortunately. Though I'm not sure why.